# How to rename a repository in SVN?

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svnserve, svn-repository

I need to rename my existing repository root name to a new name.

I am using svnserve server.

```
URL: svn://somename.dev.loc.con.dept/export/svnrepo/**old_name/CL_abc/trunk
Repository Root: svn://somename.dev.loc.con.dept/export/svnrepo/**old_name
```

1. Rename svn://somename.dev.loc.con.dept/export/svnrepo/**old_name**
   to
   svn://somename.dev.loc.con.dept/export/svnrepo/**new_name**
2. In the command line it should be:

   ```
   /export/svnrepo/**old_name**  to /export/svnrepo/**new_name**
   ```
3. Need to rename the repo name too

   CL_abc
   to
   CL_newname

Comment: Check out this solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047941/renaming-svn-repository-project-name

Comment: If you are using [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/), you can simply right-click a repository in the VisualSVN Server Manager MMC and select "Rename"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this on the Subversion server that's running the `svnserve` command. The `svnserve` command can either take the name of a repository created with the `svnadmin create` command, or a directory that contains multiple repositories created with the `svnadmin` command.

#### One Repository

```
$ hostname
$ mysvn
$ cd /opt/repos
$ svnadmin create foo
$ svnserve -r foo -d
```

#### Accessing that Repository

```
$ svn ls svn://mysvn
$ svn mkdir svn://mysvn/trunk svn://mysvn/tags svn://mysvn/branches
$ svn co svn://mysvn/trunk
```

In the above example, I created a Subversion repository called `foo`, and I ran `svnserve` with that repository as the root of the server.

When I access that repository, the URL does not have the repository name in it. The *root* of my URL is simply the machine name. There is nothing to rename.

#### Multiple Repositories

```
$ hostname
$ mysvn
$ cd /opt/repos
$ svnadmin create foo
$ svnadmin create bar
$ svnserve -r . -d
```

#### Accessing those repositories

```
$ svn ls svn://mysvn
svn: E210005: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://localhost'
svn: E210005: No repository found in 'svn://localhost'
$ svn ls svn://mysvn/foo
$ svn ls svn://mysvn/bar
$ svn mkdir svn://mysvn/bar/trunk svn://mysvn/bar/tags svn://mysvn/bar/branches
$ svn co svn://mysvn/bar/trunk
```

In this example, I created two Subversion repository directories called `foo` and `bar` under the `/opt/repos` directory. When I start up `svnserve`, I give it the name of the directory that contains my Subversion repositories. My repository names are the names of my directories. I have directories `foo` and `bar` and that's there names. If I want to change the names of the repositories, I need to change them on the server:

```
$ hostname
mysvn
$ pkill svnserve   #Stop the SVN server
$ cd /opt/repos
$ mv bar to fubar  #Change the repo name
$ svnserve -r /opt/repos -d
```

#### Accessing the repository

$ svn ls svn://mysvn/fubar/trunk

When I restart the SVN server, my repository has a new name.

It looks like you need to do the following:

```
$ ssh somename.dev.loc.con.dept  #Get on the Subversion server
$ pkill svnserve                 #Shutdown the server
$ mv /export/svnrepo/oldname /export/svnrepo/newname
$ svnserve -r / -d
```

Now, you'll be able to access your repository from the new name. However, I would recommend that you simplify your Subversion URL by starting the `svnserve` process with `/export/svnserve` as root:

```
$ svnserve -r /export/svnrepo -d
```

Now, users can access their projects with a slightly shorter name:

```
$ svn co svn://somename.dev.loc.con.dept/newname/CL_abc/trunk
```

Comment: Thanks David, thanks for the detailed description. I am a bit confused now. Please let me know if I have done something wrong here - I just need to execute the following steps 1. $ ssh somename.dev.loc.con.dept 2. $ pkill svnserve 3. $ mv /export/svnrepo/oldname /export/svnrepo/newname 4. $ svnserve -r / -d 5. $ svn co svn://somename.dev.loc.con.dept/newname/CL_abc/trunk

Comment: That it. To rename a repository using `svnserve`, you just rename the directory of that repository. I normally specify `-r` to be either the directories where the repositories reside or the repository directory itself. I don't know the behavior if you start svnserve with `/` as the repository root. Besides, you now have to specify the whole directory structure from /export in the svn URL.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. What about the working copy dir, do i need to make any changes to reflect the new URL?

Comment: You need to use `svn relocate` or in older svn clients `svn switch --relocate`. Do `svn help relocate`.

Comment: Thanks a ton David. This is perfect.