# Apache SVN commands only work with full path to repo

Tags: apache, svn-repository

**Situation:**

I'm currently setting up a new Ubuntu Server (22.04) as new test-environment for our websites with Apache subversion. When trying to do anything with a repository on the new server I always have to use the full path to the repo (The repositories are located under `/var/local/svn` on both servers).

Here are all commands I've tried, with the results:

- `svn info svn://[NewSVNserver]/TestRepo` - Doesn't work
- `svn info svn://[NewSVNserver]/svn/TestRepo` - Doesn't work
- `svn info svn://[NewSVNserver]/var/local/svn/TestRepo` - Works
- `svn info svn://[OldSVNserver]/TestRepo` - Works
- `svn info svn://[OldSVNserver]/svn/TestRepo` - Doesn't work
- `svn info svn://[OldSVNserver]/var/local/svn/TestRepo` - Doesn't work

Above, where is says 'Doesn't work', the following error message is thrown:

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL »svn://[SVNServer]/[Path]«
svn: E210005: No repository found in 'svn://[SVNServer]/[Path]'
```

---

**What I've tried:**

I'm sure it's some kind of configuration. As the above seems to apply to all repositories (including new ones) at the corresponding server, I assume it has to be some server-based configuration and not repository-based.

I've already checked, compared and adjusted the configurations on the new SVNServer, which are listed below, to the ones of the old SVNServer:

- `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
- `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf`

I've also tried adding the following from `dav_svn.conf` to `apache2.conf`:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/local/svn
</Location>
```

(After restarting Apache2 with `service apache2 restart`):
`apachectl configtest` returns `Syntax OK` but it sadly doesn't change anything

---

**The specific question:**

What configuration does one have to make, in order to change the path to the repo in `svn`-commands?

Comment: Your translated error message is almost certainly not accurate. The hyphenated "project-archive" looks especially odd. On my machine, I get "svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL ...". Consider using something like `LANGUAGE=C svn info ...` in the future.

Comment: You're right. I should not have translated the error message so roughly. I corrected it.

Comment: The [Red Bean Book on setting up httpd](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) suggests to set `SVNPath` in `httpd.conf`. Have you tried that?

Comment: [The documentation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs) states `In modern releases of Ubuntu, all configuration options have been moved to apache2.conf [...] and httpd.conf no longer exists`. As this is my case, I added `SVNParentPath /var/local/svn` to my apache2.conf. `apachectl configtest` returns `Syntax OK` but it sadly doesn't work :/

Comment: Are you sure the old server supported `server/repo`? The common thing seems to be `server/svn/repo` and that's also what's in the link I shared.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure, as it still supports it. As already mentioned: When entering `svn info svn://OldSVNServer/TestRepo` it works and even gives as output: `Path: TestRepo`, `URL: svn://OldSVNServer/TestRepo`, `Relative URL: ^/` and `Repository Root: svn://OldSVNServer/TestRepo`. It doesn't work with `svn://OldSVNServer/svn/TestRepo` or `svn://OldSVNServer/var/local/svn/TestRepo`.

Comment: I'm out of my depth concerning Apache. Let's hope someone more proficient will pick up this question. One last thing, supplementary information like your last two comments are best [edit]ed into your question. And one very last thing, out of curiosity, does `svn://NewSVNServer/svn/TestRepo` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I wasn't actively looking for a solution to this anymore, but today I stumbled upon this:

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435270/how-to-rename-a-repository-in-svn) about renaming repositories, the answer also states how to make the path to the repo obsolete. Basically, when one serves the repos via the 'svnserve -r / -d' command, one simply has to add the path to the folder in which all the repositories lie..

This did it for me:

> svnserve -r /path/to/your/repos -d

After that I could comfortably use the repo via TortoiseSVN on a Windows client without having to write out the full path to the repo every time.